# How to fix 'The available app icons include a default icon' when publishing an electron app to windows store?

Tags: reactjs, electron, windows-store-apps, windows-store, electron-builder

My electron-react project which I have open sourced here : [windows-terminal-tweaker](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/windows-terminal-tweaker)

After running `npm run release` from the `renderer` folder , it builds the app in the `renderer/dist` directory.

The `dist/TerminalTweaker` directory has all the built files along with the `.exe` file.

After this I use the `electron-windows-store` to be able to make my app publish ready. Here is my script for this :

```
const convertToWindowsStore = require('electron-windows-store')

convertToWindowsStore({
   containerVirtualization: false,
   inputDirectory: 'dist/TerminalTweaker',
   outputDirectory: 'output',
   packageVersion: '1.0.0.0',
   packageName: 'terminalTweaker',
   identityName : '<secretId>' , 
   familyName : '<secretString>' ,
   publisherDisplayName : "Natesh M Bhat" , 
   packageDisplayName: 'Terminal Tweaker',
   packageDescription: 'Tweak your windows terminal to heart\'s content with this app using its beautiful interface to configure everything about the terminal.',
   packageExecutable: 'dist/TerminalTweaker/Terminal Tweaker.exe',
   publisher: 'CN=<secretString>',
   windowsKit: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.18362.0\\x64',
   finalSay: function () {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve())
   }
})
```

Now once I get the `terminalTweaker.appx` , I uploaded this package in windows store app dashboard.

When I submit submission , its getting rejected showing the following error. How do I fix this ?

> App Policies: 10.1.1 Icon
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> The available app icons include a default icon. Icons must uniquely represent apps so users associate icons with the appropriate apps and do not confuse one app for another. For information about icons and tiles in Windows apps, see [Application Icons and Logos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets), or for 3D icons for Mixed Reality apps, see
> [3D app launcher design guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/3d-app-launcher-design-guidance).

Comment: Can you share your app's icon and how you config to use it?

Comment: @TienDuong you can see all the code along with icons in the github link i showed above. While building the package using `npm release` , the icon is attached automatically by looking at the info in the `package.json` file.

Comment: See if this helps? https://github.com/KanoComputing/kit-app-shell/blob/9840261f93ead2d8a0b1ab0b36f732fd6dc3730f/packages/windows-store/src/build.ts or https://github.com/cosadiz69/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player-UNOFFICIAL-/blob/942d688931b7ca1b69493dfcc1831682f78cd0b7/gulpfile.babel.js

Comment: @TarunLalwani , those repositories code is above my head. Since my codebase is very small , could you please suggest me what I need to change . I have mentioned the link to my repository in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the default icon provided by Electron (which is the logo of Electron). This icon will also be used in the Windows Store, and it would obviously not reflect your app.

You'll find it under this path in your case:

- `windows-terminal-tweaker/renderer/public/favicon.ico`

You probably just forgot to change that file too, as every other icon seems to work :)

Comment: I made the changes u suggested and submitted to the store. It says rejected for the same reason again. What shall I do?