# Electron appx default electron icon used in start menu

Tags: electron, windows-store-apps, electron-builder, appx

I am trying to submit my electron app to the windows store but whenever I do It gets rejected for this reason:

```
App Policies: 10.1.1 Inaccurate Representation - Icon

Notes To Developer

The available product tile icons include a default image. Tile icons must uniquely represent product so users associate icons with the appropriate products and do not confuse one product for another. For information about tiles see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets, or for 3D icons for Mixed Reality products, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/3d-app-launcher-design-guidance.
```

I asked for more info and got a video showing that my app is using the default electron icon and thats the reason for it getting rejected, I've tried everything to make sure my app never uses the default electron icon but no luck.

In order to build, sign, and submit my appx file, I run the following commands on then `appxBuild` branch of this repo: https://github.com/MartinBarker/RenderTune/tree/appxBuild

1. Run `electron-builder build --win` to build the dist/win-unpacked folder
   [image]
2. Run the following powershell command to sign my appx file and export it to the folder `output-appx`:

```
electron-windows-store --input-directory C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\RenderTune\dist\win-unpacked --output-directory C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\RenderTuneAppx --package-version 0.0.2.0 --package-name RenderTune --package-display-name 'RenderTune' --publisher-display-name `martinbarker' --identity-name 1845martinbarker.digify -a C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\RenderTune\Resources\
```

If I click the outputted appx file and install it, I can see my custom icon being used [image]

Except for if I search for my app in the windows explorer menu I see the default electron app icon and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this issue.
[image]

The finished \output-appx\RenderTune.appx file can be uploaded and submitted to my windows store app page fine so I dont think the credentials signing are incorrect, but once it gets reviewed it always gets rejected with this tile rejection message.

I've tried following various different guides on how to submit an electron app to the windows store online:
https://www.electron.build/configuration/appx
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide
https://blog.mifi.no/2020/03/31/automated-electron-build-with-release-to-mac-app-store-microsoft-store-snapcraft/
https://github.com/MartinBarker/RenderTune/tree/appxBuild/build/appx)
[How to fix 'The available app icons include a default icon' when publishing an electron app to windows store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310667/how-to-fix-the-available-app-icons-include-a-default-icon-when-publishing-an-e)

And made sure I have a folder `build/appx` and `resources/` that have all my needed image files:
[image]

Inside my package.json for the build windows section I specify my icon as an ico file:

```
    "win": {
      "target": ["appx"],
      "extraResources": [
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-ffprobe-static/ffmpeg.exe",
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-ffprobe-static/ffprobe.exe"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      
    "appx": {
      "applicationId": "RenderTune",
      "identityName": "1845martinbarker.digify",
      "publisher": "CN=E69B865D-5831-4BE5-9AA4-08E27DAAD66C",
      "publisherDisplayName": "martinbarker",
      "backgroundColor":"#a0beeb"
    }
```

Comment: ive tried adding code to main.js to set the browserWindow icon but no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351575/how-to-change-electronjs-app-default-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, I was missing a tile image png file

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific about what exactly was missing and how did you solve the problem so that it would be useful for others who encounter this problem

Comment: Had to check his repo to understand this answer. Found the repo here https://github.com/MartinBarker/RenderTune/tree/appxBuild/build

Comment: My assumption is that the files `build/appx/SmallTile.png` and build/appx/LargeTile.png` were the files he was missing

Answer (score 0):

Got the same `App Policies: 10.1.1 Inaccurate Representation - Icon` as OP and turns out I need to define ALL the icons from the documentation here:

https://www.electron.build/configuration/appx.html

I've listed all the icons below in case the documentation changes:

- **Logo**: StoreLogo.png
- **Square150x150Logo**: Square150x150Logo.png
- **Square44x44Logo**: Square44x44Logo.png
- **Wide310x150Logo**: Wide310x150Logo.png
- *Optional* **BadgeLogo**: BadgeLogo.png
- *Optional* **Square310x310Logo**: LargeTile.png
- *Optional* **Square71x71Logo**: SmallTile.png
- *Optional* **SplashScreen**: SplashScreen.png

Also double check the files are in `/build/appx` (the documentation isn't 100% clear on that)

For icon sizes, there's a good post here (and I also confirmed in Visual Studio):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61805906/3847

It also pays to double check the `.appx` file is bundled correctly. Just extract using any zip extraction utility, and make sure the icon files are in `/assets`, and also double check they're all defined in the `AppxManifest.xml`.